# Neo4j merging all nodes

Tags: neo4j

I have a simple dataset as below[image]

and I have import in to neo4j.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM "file:///testset.csv" AS line WITH line

MERGE (b:Buyer {name: line.`trader`})
MERGE (s:Seller {name:line.`countertrade`})


CREATE (b)-[r:buy{amount:line.`price`}]->(s)
SET r.amount = tofloat(r.amount)

;
```

The output from the query shows

```
MATCH p=()-[r:buy]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25
```

[image]

The blue is the trader and the pink is countertrade

> However, I would like to see the whole map of relationship
>   (bidirectional). So the nodes will be pointing to each other and the
>   total nodes will be reduced from 6 to 3. The relationship will remain
>   the same as 6. I would like to know whether neo4j can do it. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should really use a single node label :Company rather than :Buyer and :Seller, that will ensure when you MERGE that you will only have a single distinct node per company, so 3 nodes total.

Since companies can both buy and sell, it doesn't make sense to model that as a label, that's already captured in your directed :buy relationships.

Comment: Thank you for help! Because I am very new for neo4j

Comment: If I change my csv to company on both columns. How should I write my cipher query?

Comment: You can keep your CSV as-is, just use :Company label for both nodes: `MERGE (b:Company {name: line.\`trader\`}) MERGE (s:Company {name:line.\`countertrade\`})`